# Typescript interface extends two component types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So this will output an `<input>` element - everything works perfectly:

```
interface InputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  error?: FieldError;
  icon?: string;
  id: string;
  register?: UseFormRegisterReturn;
}

const StyledInputComponent = styled.input`
...
`

const MyComponent = ({
  error,
  icon,
  id,
  register,
  onChange,
  ...props
}: InputProps) => {
  return (
    <StyledInputComponent
     hasError={!!error}
     id={id}
     onChange={onChange}
     placeholder={placeholder}
     type={type}
     {...register}
     {...props}
    />
  });
};
```

I now need to be able to have the consuming component choose between an `<input>` and a `<textarea>`.

The problem I have is that (I think) I need to extend the interface further like this:

```
interface InputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement> {
  error?: FieldError;
  icon?: string;
  id: string;
  inputType?: "input" | "textarea";
  register?: UseFormRegisterReturn;
}
```

And I'm just using the new `inputType` prop to switch between outputted components:

```
{ inputType === "input" &&  
  <StyledInputComponent
   hasError={!!error}
   id={id}
   onChange={onChange}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   type={type}
   {...register}
   {...props}
  />
}
{ inputType === "textarea" &&  
 <StyledTextAreaComponent
  hasError={!!error}
  id={id}
  onChange={onChange}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  rows={4}
  {...register}
  {...props}
 />
}
```

However, trying to extend the interface for both an `<input>` and a `<textarea>` has lead to numerous errors, all along these lines:
[image: errors]

What's the right way to go about resolving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component cannot extend the props of `input` AND `textarea` because they have they both have properties with some of the same names, but different types.

So your component should only extends *one* of these, depending on what is passed as the `inputType`.

That means you need generics here.

For example:

```
type InputProps<T extends 'input' | 'textarea'> = {
  id: string;
  inputType?: T;
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
```

Here `JSX.InstrinsicElements['tagnamehere']` will return the props that react would allow for that tag name. And `T` is set by the value of `inputType`, which is either `input` or `textarea`.

Now you just need to make you component generic as well, and pass that generic to the props type:

```
function MyComponent<T extends 'input' | 'textarea'>(props: InputProps<T>) {
    return <></>
}
```

Now to test it out:

```
// no type errors
const testInput = <MyComponent id="123" inputType='input' checked />
const testTextarea = <MyComponent id="456" inputType='textarea' rows={10} />

// type error, can't use input prop on a textarea
const testBadProps = <MyComponent id="456" inputType='textarea' checked />
//                                                              ^ type error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=77&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOASQDswBXGABRzAGcAeAFThIAHjCQMAJlwLAmrfHAA+BUSJREU+AHxwAvHADepOHGDiAXHC4woMgOYBuIydkw+1JAH4LfRwF84AGRwAFIAygAaAHSM1jJcwGgAogA2SCBiMFwA2nwAuuSYzAwYwBAMcACylADCuJAMGfyCImKS0i7ySvgqMGqoWgAUYJxcFows7CP8mgCUBk7GRDDMUOU8mjwA9JqkvuSbm3AMEHBUNIJQOFBcpGhlVqdIVuOsunA8VbXgZRkm4joAIgAjAAmADMAOcEzcNB0+BkE3kaAAFkg0ABrJDiODbW73eCiKx8YS9dRvD41Oo-BjwUyAgAsAFYAGyQhGsGFIOE9PoaOA4ADuXB0+iBAAZ-LjSAdTu4LlcADRwNAoBjdODMLi0dnwYYQMBwMpwFCPVTqPEMB6EmAAIRQ4g4+qkegpX3qvzpAKZrKhHPc3JJvKRqIxWJxOxlxij0Zjsbj8YTibjAD1ZeckJdoEA)

Comment: Hey @Alex - just wanted to say thanks for taking the time to write such a complete and in depth solution, it's very much appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your solution, but I have some problems when returning an input text or a textarea

```
function MyComponent<T extends 'input' | 'textarea'>(props: InputProps<T>) {
  const {inputType, ...rest} = props;

  if (inputType === "input") {
    return <input
//          ^error
      type={"text"}
      {...rest}
    />
  }

  if (inputType === "textarea") {  
    return <textarea
//          ^error
      {...rest}
    />
  }
  
  return null
}
```

This are the returned errors:

```
Type '{ type: "text"; } & Omit<InputProps<T>, "inputType">' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Type '{ type: "text"; } & Omit<InputProps<T>, "inputType">' is not assignable to type 'ClassAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
    Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
      Type 'InputProps<T>["ref"] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.
```

[playground with error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOASQDswBXGABRzAGcAeAFThIAHjCQMAJlwLAmrfHAA%20BUSJREU%20AHxwAvHADepOHBksYfakgD8ALjh8A3KQC%20cAGRwAUgGUAGgDpGGCgZLmA0AFEAGyQQMRguAG0%20AF1yTGYGDGAIBjgAWUoAYVxIBnj%20QRExSWlZGHklfBUYNVQtAAowTi47RjMOCG5%20TQBKAyM4NFyueH1TVgsaABo4f3WiWdc9bqGuJ0ngTDgOhfNLXR09ACIz6-HDY2MiGGYoPJ4zyae4KhodfTXFrXZzfJ76db%20TYwUE-AD0mkmoMOx1O9SWtCuNxabRQ9wMxjBLzeHxx6jBxghGyQWzBCKRk0mxPecAYzCiURc5DhcNZEF%20FyQUBwUC4pGmDFmvxpMH6rF0cB4hRK4Fy8RM6MsOnwZ3kaAAFkg0ABrJDiOD0iVS0SzPjCVrqBVK4qlNUMeBnDHasntOA4ADuXABAEYAAyuemkHkCmiCYXQVZoFAMZpwZhcWhnOC7MBwXJwFDS1Tkq3wG0wABCKHEg24TuVrvK7o1Zi9zXtuL1hpNZotiOjP0HQ%20HI9HY-HcAAejHaEKRUA)

I can solve the problem if the `rest` variable is casted to `JSX.IntrinsicElements["input"]` or `JSX.IntrinsicElements["textarea"]`... but I don't think is the best solution... Any alternative?

[playground solved casting the rest variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOASQDswBXGABRzAGcAeAFThIAHjCQMAJlwLAmrfHAA%20BUSJREU%20AHxwAvHADepOHBksYfakgD8ALjh8A3KQC%20cAGRwAUgGUAGgDpGGCgZLmA0AFEAGyQQMRguAG0%20AF1yTGYGDGAIBjgAWUoAYVxIBnj%20QRExSWlZGHklfBUYNVQtAAowTi47RjMOCG5%20TQBKAyM4NFyueH1TVgsaABo4f3WiWdc9bqGuJ0ngTDgOhfNLXR09ACIz6-HDY2MiGGYoPJ4zyae4KhodfTXFrXZzfJ76db%20TbwFBSHwBIIhBhhSIxOIMBKJW71a4pUE-AD0mkmoMOx1O9SWtCuNxabRQ9wMxjBLzeHzp6jBxghGyQs2MsK8fkCGKRKOisXiSSBwla6lx%20KeRJJk0mrPecAYzCiURc5AJBM1EF%20FyQUBwUC4pGmyPgolm-VYujgPEKJXAuXiJkplh0%20DO8jQAAskGgANZIcRwZU2-n28yy%20nO13FUqejHesxUv0c9pwHAAdy4AIAjAAGVzK0gGk00QTm6CrNAoBjNODMLi0M5wXZgOC5OAoX6Jzmxu18mAAIRQ4kG3GTbrT5QzZ2zzRHeeDoYjUeVNZ%20B8PR%20PJ9PZ7gAD1a7QzRagA)